# how to run sql query in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a script that enters a database, runs a query and discards the result in an html interface
Does anyone know a working solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

I find this solution:

Set obj = createobject(“ADODB.Connection”)
Set obj1 = createobject(“ADODB.RecordSet”)
Dim dbquery
Dbquery=”Select acctno from dbo.acct where name = ‘Harsh’”
obj.Open“Provider=SQLQLEDB;Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;UserId=test;Password=P@123;Database =AUTODB”
obj1.Open dbquery,obj
val1 = obj1.fields.item(0)
msgbox val1
obj.close
obj1.close
Set obj1=Nothing
Set obj=Nothing

but I couldn't get it to clear the contents of the query.